# Cypress Testing - for URL matching

Tags: cypress

I am trying to write a cypress test to confirm that the user is brought to the correct page after submitting a form. But I am having trouble using the regex when the digit is nested in the URL... see below for what I am looking to test for.

```js
 cy.url().should('match', /some-cool-page/with-stuff/ALLOW ANY DIGIT HERE/final/)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be just a regex, nothing special in Cypress.

```js
cy
  .url()
  .should('match', /\/some-cool-page\/with-stuff\/\d+\/final\//)
```

Regex is surrounded by `//`, so if you want to match `/`, it needs to be escaped.
A digit could be matched with `\d`, if you want to match one or more, you add `+` after it.

Comment: Thanks for the help with regex